# How to sync sqlite database with mysql database other than creating a web service

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Any help regarding sync sqlite database with mysql database other than using web service.

Comment: You should expand on what you are trying to do.  I am assuming that your MySQL database is for central storage while SQLite is for local data.

Comment: I don;t think that looking for ugly workarounds to just not create a web service can have a correct solution. I don't see any reasons why you should not create a web service.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear to me.
If you are trying to sync between client and server then you can use android "Sync Adapter"

https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Please tell more about what you want exactly for clear answer.

Comment: There is a web version and also an android app version of project.Any changes made in mysql should update data in sqlite and also any changes in sqlite should update data in mysql.So we need to sync sqlite with mysql.This is what we trying to do.

Comment: Any example or tutorial regarding sync adapters as there is no proper material regarding sync adapters on google.